# iCarousel select first index while to loading view

Tags: iphone, ios, icarousel

In my project I have a `iCarousel` in one view.Everything working fine for me. But my problem is, I want to keep the first index object at the center of the view when that view gets loaded.Am displaying totally three images in the carousel.Now the first image is loading at the right corner.I want to keep it in center while loading.How can I do this.? please share your ideas.

Comment: hey where are you, is your problem solved?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `iCarouselOptionWrap` to do this task..  Just implement this `delegate`

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    //customize carousel display
    switch (option)
    {
        case iCarouselOptionWrap:
        {
            //normally you would hard-code this to YES or NO
            return YES;
        }
        case iCarouselOptionSpacing:
        {
            //add a bit of spacing between the item views
            return value * 1.05f;
        }
        case iCarouselOptionFadeMax:
        {
            if (carouselForUser.type == iCarouselTypeCustom)
            {
                //set opacity based on distance from camera
                return 0.0f;
            }
            return value;
        }
        default:
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hai, my problem solved when I used the delegate method - (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel with return 0;Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Your welcome brother..don't forget to accept answer and +1  for this.. :)

Comment: 0 is the default for numberOfPlaceholders - you should just omit the method completely.

Comment: hi @NickLockwood, i have one question... i am implementing 2 carousel in a view...and adding  different different imageView in both, now when i am selecting 2d carousel imageview then i want to change the image in the first carousel.  i implemented this but for zero index of  first carousel i am getting crash..

Comment: @Rajneesh071 It's awkward to answer questions in a comment - create a new StackOverflow question including your view controller code and I'll answer it there.

Comment: @NickLockwood ok i will update u whenever question pasted by me:)